# How to use validation to make sure cell value starts with specific word

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, data-validation

I need to check if the value of a cell starts with the term `superuser`.
The entered value then should, for example, look like this:

```
superuser template
```

If the user enters `super user template` (with a space), then an error message should show up.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would using a drop down list be not a better solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a 'custom' validation. This gives you a formula option.

Here is an example formula that you can customize:

```
=IF(LEFT(D5,9)="superuser",1,0)
```

So, you would select the cell (ex. has d5), select data validation, choose allow 'custom', enter formula.  Formula should return 1 if valid and 0 if invalid.

Notice that I entered D5 for the formula.  If you copy and paste, Excel will change this cell address for you (which is really useful).

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you know exactly what string your are checking for this should work (assuming checked cell is A1).  Basically it checks if the first 9 characters are superuser and returns a true or false.  You can change the number and checked term to whatever you need.

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,9)="superuser","True","False")
```